# Reactive form not display in html

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following code. However the form in not getting displayed. 
Can someone let me know what is wrong with this code.

```
 <tfoot>
             <form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="type" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <ng-select [items]="parameterType" formControlName="parametertype" [clearable]="false" bindLabel="text" bindValue="id"></ng-select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ng-select [items]="defaultValues" formControlName="defaultValue" [clearable]="false" bindLabel="text" bindValue="id"></ng-select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input formControlName="description" class="form-control" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">
                Submit
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>

</form>
```

And here is my method in component.

```
 ngOnInit() {
                this.profileForm = this._formBuilder.group({
                  'type': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
                  'parametertype': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
                  'defaultValue': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
                  'description': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]]
                });
              }
```

Comment: any errors ? any way your form is invalid

Comment: I doubt it's valid HTML to have a form element inside a tfoot element. Put your form element outside of the table

Comment: @Yahiya can you define `profileForm: FormGroup` in your class

Comment: try `<form *ngIf="profileForm"  [formGroup]="profileForm" ...>` to avoid initials errors

Answer (score 0):

`form` element is not allowed in any table-related elements.Try using form tag outside the table element.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
    <tfoot [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```